# how can we add image in Twitter Auth code?

Tags: iphone, twitter

i want send image in twitter code . i am using twitter auth code. and also if i enter more code then it not coming.

i m using sanded twitter auth code.
https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/issues/

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can't add image on twitter. you can link your image instead using imageshack API.

http://www.yfrog.com/

http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/